# how to dismiss current presenting controller and navigate to other controller using navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

```
self.dismiss(animated: false) {
  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController will only have a value if your ViewController is embedded in an UINavigationController otherwise it will be nil.
In your case it is nil, so your controller is dismissed successfully but **ViewController** is not pushed.

In your completion block use **self.presentingViewController** to push the object.

```
self.dismiss(animated: false) {
  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
  self.presentingViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: that's not work. current controller dismiss but not navigate to other

Comment: Just print(self.presentingViewController?.navigationController) and check it has a value or not.